# Where should InitializeComponent() appear in code order?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

If I create a winForms "myForm" then the following boiler plate code is generated:

```
public partial class myForm: Form
{
    public myForm() 
    {

       //<<position 1

       InitializeComponent();

       //<<position 2

    } 
}
```

If I add extra code to the constructor method does it make any difference to the running of the app if I place my code in position 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it does.

`InitializeComponent` is the method that VS generates that is responsible for creating and positioning the controls on a form.

Code in "position 1" will execute before the controls exist.  If you try to access a control in this position, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` (say, if you try to set the content of a `TextBox`).  Similar code in "position 2" will work as expected.

There is use to "position 1" though: if you have custom controls or behaviour that rely on properties of your form, setting those properties in "position 1" might prevent that code from having to refresh if you allow controls to be created before those values are set.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Before InitializeComponent all controls have not been created yet.

Answer (score 2):

in the function InitializeComponent(); you create all of your objects you put in the graphical layout. if you want to access them, your code should be in position2.

Answer (score 1):

The `button`,`textbox`,`combobox` that you put on the `Form` automatically creates some code.This code  is generated in  `InitializeComponent()`

So calling the controls that you put on Form from `position 1` is **wrong** because the controls are never created at that point of code.

You can call and access the controls that you put on the Form from `position 2`

Comment: thanks - but as some of the other answers mention - position 1 can be used in some circumstances

Answer (score 0):

Like the others here have said, position 2 should be used in most cases. However, there are exceptions where neither of the positions will work, and you will actually have to attach your code to another event.

Example: You have a **ScrollViewer** and an **Image** inside it. You insert a big image file in the **Image** component and want to show it so the center of the image is visible at the start, with an option to scroll around to see the rest of the image:

```
scrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer1.ScrollableHeight / 2);
```

However writing this in the constructor either before or after *InitializeComponent()* (or even in) will not give you the result you want. (Because, even though the components have been initialized at this stage, the contained image file has not.) Instead what you have to do, is attach a new **Event Handler** *ImageOpened* to the **Image** and write the command there.

[image: ImageOpened EventHandler]