# C# Xamarin Forms Code not executing when loading but executing on button click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation

I have the same exact code running on `Page` opening and `Button` click.
This is the code on load:

```
[Obsolete]
public LoginPage()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        User results = await LoginService.Login(username.Text.Trim(), password.Text.Trim());
        if (results != null)
        {
            GlobalVars.loginProfilJsonObject = results;
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
            Console.WriteLine("Not executing");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Wrong email address or password", "OK");
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the button click:

```
[Obsolete]
async void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User results = await LoginService.Login(username.Text.Trim(), password.Text.Trim());
    if (results != null)
    {
        GlobalVars.loginProfilJsonObject = results;
        Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Wrong email address or password", "OK");
    }        
}
```

I tried a `try...catch` to try to get any errors but nothing.
It has to do with this line i guess but I can not seem to understand what this is; `Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();`.
Nothing is executed after that line.
This happened after I updated to latest `Xamarin.Forms` version.

Edit: The page is called through `MainPage` after check to perform login

```
    if (GlobalVars.loginProfilJsonObject == null)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        });
    }
```

Comment: "Nothing is executed after that line" - that's the last line in the block.   What do you expect to execute next?

Comment: For example a Console.WriteLine. I will add it for you ;)

Comment: @Jason I expect that same line to Execute

Comment: wouldn't creating a new MainPage execute the same load again, which creates a new MainPage that executes the load again.. etc?

Comment: No because after login is done, it won't be called again

Comment: I would suggest setting the Exception Settings to catch ANY Exception thrown:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    User results = await LoginService.Login(username.Text.Trim(), password.Text.Trim());
    if (results != null)
    {
        GlobalVars.loginProfilJsonObject = results;
        Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
        Console.WriteLine("Not executing");
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Wrong email address or password", "OK");
    }
}
```

OnAppearing method executed after the page is displayed.

Comment: Could this be the case? It only started happening after I updated to latest Xamarin.Forms.
I will test it.

Comment: The method is called after InitializeComponent but it is still getting blocked. The solution works but I don't understand why code executed before InitializeComponent is finished.
Anyway, thank you

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965882/where-should-initializecomponent-appear-in-code-order

Comment: But anyway, I think that maybe MVVM architecture could help you, move the service call to your ViewModel, and use a command to execute the service call from your view.